# create a diffrent Property(Mail Java API) object for each service() call in my Servlet?

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, jakarta-mail

Hi i have a servlet from which i want to send E-mail to clients. I am using Google App Engine to Host my application. I want to know if I can create an object of property and session in servlets init and use it every time a request comes instead of creating new one for each request ?

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException, ServletException 
{

//Retrieve stuff from form above

Properties props = new Properties(); 
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null); //Create once and reuse 
//for each request?

        String msgBody = "...";

        try {
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("admin@example.com", "Example.com Admin"));
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                             new InternetAddress("user@example.com", "Mr. User"));
            msg.setSubject("Your Example.com account has been activated");
            msg.setText(msgBody);
            Transport.send(msg);

        } catch (AddressException e) {
            // ...
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // ...
        }
}
```

Comment: are your trying to send emails with different settings?

Comment: @jirungaray No same settings, just different email id for different requests.

Comment: You mean a different from field?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new Session for each identity you're using to connect to your email server, and you [SHOULD NOT use Session.getDefaultInstance](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#getdefaultinstance).

Comment: This is the correct explanation for why your properties don't seem to be set in the way you expect. Make sure to CTRL + F for "getDefaultInstance"

Comment: For something which only needs to exist for the request, use request parameters. For something you want to persist across requests, use sessions. Pretty much the golden rule.